# replace string in double quotes - java

Tags: java, regex

I am reading a file and storing into a string variable input :

`"returnonassets":{"content":"5.97%","term":"ttm"},"float":"332400000","ex_dividenddate":"dec 27, 2013","payoutratio":"23.00%","qtrlyearningsgrowth":{"content":"8.90%","term":"yoy"}`

I want to replace `"float":"332400000"` to `"floatShare":"332400000"`, i tried following commands but didnt worked :

```
input.replaceAll("\"float\"", "\"floatShare\"");
```

Edit:

this is my append command to StringBuilder sb:

```
sb.append(input.toString().replaceAll("-", "").replaceAll("\"float\"", "\"floatShare\"").toLowerCase()).append("\n");
```

Comment: `String` is immutable. Does `replaceAll` return something?

Comment: i added how i am appending to stringbuilder sb, dashes were removed.

Comment: Explain what you mean by `_didnt worked_`? What were you expecting? What actually happened?

Comment: The code you have in your question works for me.

Comment: sry i am still getting same string which contain `"float":"332400000"`

Comment: Looks like all you need is to replace `float` with `floatShare`.

Comment: i have pasted partial input, float is present at other place also - thats why i was looking for this pattern : `"float"`

Comment: How are you using the `sb`? This should work fine.

Comment: i am appending every thing to sb, and finally i am doing sb.toString() to get the ouput - rest operations are working - dashes, new line and lowerCase(). i think escaping quotes is the prob its not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Strings in Java are immutable. The way your code is at the moment, you are getting a new string object from `input.replaceAll("\"float\"", "\"floatShare\"");`, but not doing anything with it. Solving the problem is simple.
Instead of doing:

```
input.replaceAll("\"float\"", "\"floatShare\"");
```

do

```
input = input.replaceAll("\"float\"", "\"floatShare\"");
```

Comment: See the `StringBuilder` code at the end of their question. They aren't re-using `input`. They're building a new `String`.